# How to solve $\sqrt{\tan x}=1$ without squaring?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Problem:**

$$\sqrt{\tan x}=1$$

**Solution (with squaring):**

$$\sqrt{\tan x}=1$$

$$\tan x=1$$

$$x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{1}$$

**1.** $(i)$ contains extraneous roots. How do I filter them out?

**2.** How do I solve for $x$ without squaring?

Comment: Can $\sqrt{\tan x}$ be $-1$?

Comment: @J.G. No sir that's impossible as we know, $\sqrt{x^{2}}=|x|$

Comment: So how are any roots of (i) extraneous?

Comment: tip: to label equations in mathjax, one way is to append `\tag{1}` , `tag{My Uncle Bob}` , etc.

Comment: @RyanG I edited it; thanks!!!

Comment: You can filter extraneous solutions by putting $x=n\pi+\pi/4$ in $\sqrt{\tan x}=1$, obviously here there are none since $\sqrt{\tan(n\pi+\pi/4)}=\sqrt{\tan(\pi/4)}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need squaring since we know that

> $$\sqrt A=1 \iff A=1$$

therefore

$$\sqrt{\tan x}=1 \iff \tan x=1 \iff x=\frac \pi 4 +n\pi$$

and we don't have extraneous solutions.

---

**Edit**

In case we want obtain the solution by squaring, we have in general that for $A>0$ and $B>0$

$$\sqrt A = B \iff A=B^2$$

and for this reason, also proceeding in this way, we don't have extraneous solutions.

Answer (score 7):

The following $2$ cases are definitely different from each other:

$$\require{cancel} A=B\hspace{1em}\cancel{\hspace{-1em}{\iff}\hspace{-1em}}\hspace{1em}A^2=B^2$$

Because, if $A$ and $B$ have opposite signs, then the statement fails.

The correct statement should be:

$$\left|A\right|=\left|B\right|\iff A^2=B^2$$

---

However, the statement $\sqrt {A}=B$ immediately tells us that $A,B≥0$.

This is based on the following definition:

$$\sqrt {x^2}=|x|≥0,\thinspace x\in\mathbb R$$

Thus we have,

$$\left|\sqrt{A}\right|=\left|B\right|\iff \sqrt A=B$$

This follows,

$$\sqrt A=B\iff A=B^2$$

where $A,B≥0$.

This means, in this case we don't have extraneous roots.

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the accepted since it details just why that bidrectional statement is accurate. The accepted answer can be easily misunderstood by a student with a tenuous grasp on square roots.

Answer (score 3):

> $$\sqrt{\tan x}=1\\\tan x=1\\x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

You have shown that $$\sqrt{\tan x}=1\implies\tan x=1\implies x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$$ (the given equation's implicit condition that $\tan x\ge0$ justifies $\left(\sqrt{\tan x}\right)^2=\tan x$ in the first step).

But notice also that $$x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\implies\tan x=1\implies\sqrt{\tan x}=1$$ (taking principal square root in the last step).

Therefore, in this example, all three lines are equivalent to one another; so, no extraneous root has been created. Hence, squaring does not **necessarily** create extraneous roots.