# Extra solutions when solving $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2\sin2\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

**The problem:**

$$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2\sin2\theta}$$

**My solution:**

$$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2\sin2\theta}$$

$$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2\times2\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$

$$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=2\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$

$$\sin\theta-2\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}+\cos\theta=0$$

$$(\sqrt{\sin\theta}-\sqrt{\cos\theta})^2=0$$

$$\sqrt{\sin\theta}=\sqrt{\cos\theta}$$

Either $\cos\theta$ or $\sin\theta$ can be equal to zero. Both can't be equal to zero at the same time. As we can see that $\sqrt{\sin\theta}=\sqrt{\cos\theta}$, neither of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ is equal to zero. So, dividing both sides by $\cos\theta$ is valid.

$$\sqrt{\tan\theta}=1$$

$$\tan\theta=1$$

$$\theta=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{1}$$

**My question:**

1. We've stumbled upon an interesting solution in (1). Here, $\theta$ satisfies our original equation only when $n$ is even or $0$. Why is that? Isn't $n$ supposed to belong to the set of integers?

**PS:** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4260843/768162) might help you in answering the question.

Comment: Note that the square root is only defined for positive values of $\sin\theta$ or $\cos\theta$, or whatever you put under the square root. When you devide by $\sqrt{\cos\theta}$ you may change the set of solutions, the same applies when you square.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> **My solution:** $$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2\sin2\theta}$$
>
> $$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2\times2\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$
>
> $$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=2\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$
>
> $$\sin\theta-2\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}+\cos\theta=0$$
>
> $$(\sqrt{\sin\theta}-\sqrt{\cos\theta})^2=0\tag{*}$$
>
> $$\sqrt{\sin\theta}=\sqrt{\cos\theta}$$
>
> $$\sqrt{\tan\theta}=1\tag#$$
>
> $$\tan\theta=1$$
>
> $$\theta=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

1. Note that $$\frac{\sqrt{\sin\theta}}{\sqrt{\cos\theta}}=1\implies\sqrt{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}=1$$  but $$\sqrt{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}=1\kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies\frac{\sqrt{\sin\theta}}{\sqrt{\cos\theta}}=1;$$ [so](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/noeg5qewzr), $$\dfrac{\sqrt{\sin\theta}}{\sqrt{\cos\theta}}\not\equiv\sqrt{\tan\theta}.$$ In step $(\#)$, you introduced [extraneous solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4243037/21813)—expanding the set of *candidate solutions*—by allowing $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ to be both negative (as well as both positive).

   Nevertheless, $(\#)$ is a **valid** step, as the forward implication is correct.
2. However, the above may be moot, since the prior step $(*)$ may have discarded solutions and thus may be **invalid**: without justification, it is not apparent that $$\sin\theta-2\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}+\cos\theta=0\implies(\sqrt{\sin\theta}-\sqrt{\cos\theta})^2=0,$$ since \begin{align}&{}{}\sin\theta-2\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}+\cos\theta\\\not\equiv&{}{}\sin\theta-2\sqrt{\sin\theta}\sqrt{\cos\theta}+\cos\theta\\\equiv&{}{}(\sqrt{\sin\theta}-\sqrt{\cos\theta})^2.\end{align}

   (The converse is certainly true though.)

   Here, the forward-implication [does](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/afxhgdj9wq) turn out to be justifiable: $\theta$ happens to reside in the first quadrant, so $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are indeed both positive.

---

**Addendum 1: suggested solution**
\begin{align}&{}\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2\sin2\theta}\\
\color{red}\implies &{}1+\sin2\theta=2\sin2\theta\\
\iff &{}\sin2\theta=1\\ \iff&{}\theta=(4n+1)\frac\pi4.\tag1\end{align} The first step above turns out to have introduced extraneous solutions $(\text{for example, }\frac{5\pi}4),$ which we must prune out. Alternatively, we could note the implicit restriction (changing the $\color{red}\implies$ to $\color{red}\iff)$ $$\sin\theta+\cos\theta\geq0\\
\sqrt2\sin\left(\theta+\frac\pi4\right)\geq0\\
\theta+\frac\pi4\in\bigcup[2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi]$$
$$\theta\in\bigcup[(8n-1)\frac\pi4,(8n+3)\frac\pi4].\tag2$$ Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$: $$\theta=(8k+1)\frac\pi4\\=\frac\pi4+2k\pi.$$

---

**Addendum 2**

> So, steps that create extraneous roots are still valid.

We are [arguing](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232127/21813) from mathematical axioms and given a context, so **the step $\big(Q(x)\to R(x)\big)$ is valid precisely when it is mathematically true in that context.**

For example, given $(x-3)(x-4)=0,$ the step $\big(x\in\{3,4\}{\implies} x\in\{3,4,7\}\big)$ is valid, even though it makes the *candidate solution set* less precise; however, it isn't valid to then deduce that $\big((x-3)(x-4)=0{\iff} x\in\{3,4,7\}\big),$ that is, that the *actual solution set* is $\{3,4,7\}.$

> However, steps that discard solutions are invalid, right?

Yes, $\big(x\in\{3,4\}{\implies}x\in\{4\}\big)$ is an invalid step.

> Also, I think that (*) might be valid because $\theta$ is in the first quadrant: see @user's answer. If $\theta$ is in the first quadrant, then $\sin\theta=|\sin\theta|$ & $\cos\theta=|\cos\theta|.$

Yes, $(*)$ turns out to be a valid step.  But since you had neither shown (using the given equation's implicit conditions) nor even asserted that $θ$ in fact lies in quadrant $1$ (rather than quadrant $3),$ your presentation there may be too sketchy/hand-wavy.

Comment: You squared both sides in the 2nd line of your solution. Didn't you create extraneous roots?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Squaring does *potentially* (though [not necessarily](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260867/21813)) create extraneous solutions, which were exactly what we were accounting for in $(2).$ (With this restriction, the second line effectively becomes an $\iff$.)

Comment: So, steps that create extraneous roots are still valid. However, steps that discard solutions are invalid, right?

Comment: Also, I think that (*) might be valid because $\theta$ is in the first quadrant: see @user's answer. If $\theta$ is in the first quadrant, then $\sin\theta=|\sin\theta|$ & $\cos\theta=|\cos\theta|$. What do you think?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic : Steps that create extraneous roots are not automatically valid.  If you use a step that potentially creates extraneous roots, all solutions that you find must be checked for correctness.

Answer (score 8):

$\sin \theta+\cos \theta$ is given to be **positive** square root of $2 \sin (2 \theta)$. Odd values of $n$ make $\sin \theta+\cos \theta$ negative, so only even values are permitted.

Answer (score 6):

We need that $\sin2\theta\ge 0$ that is

$$0+2n\pi\le2\theta \le \pi+2n\pi \quad \iff \quad n\pi\le \theta \le \frac \pi 2+n\pi$$

therefore only solutions in the first or third quadrant are allowed but since in the third quadrant $\sin \theta + \cos \theta <0$, only solutions in the $\color{red}{\text{first quadrant}}$ are allowed that is by $n=2k$

$$\color{red}{2k\pi\le \theta \le \frac \pi 2+2k\pi}$$

Then, since all terms involved in the expression are positive, and we have that for $A,B\ge 0$

> $$A=\sqrt B \iff A^2=B$$

we can then proceed by squaring both side to obtain an $\color{magenta}{\text{equivalent equation}}$

$$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt{2\sin2\theta} \iff 1+\sin 2\theta =2 \sin 2\theta \iff \color{magenta}{\sin 2\theta =1} $$

$$\iff2\theta=\frac \pi 2+2n\pi  \iff \theta=\frac \pi 4+n\pi\iff \color{magenta}{\theta=\frac \pi 4+2k\pi}$$

---

**Edit**

As an alternative approach, since all terms involved in the expression are positive, by AM-GM we obtain

$$\sin\theta+\cos\theta \ge 2\sqrt{\sin \theta \cos \theta}=\sqrt{2\sin 2\theta}$$

with equality for $\sin\theta=\cos\theta \implies \theta=\frac \pi 4+2k\pi$.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't completely understand the conditions you set up to make $\sin2\theta$ positive. I'm talking about $0+2kπ≤2θ≤π+2kπ⟺kπ≤θ≤\frac{π}{2}+kπ$. If possible, could you please try to present a more dumbed-down picture with more words?

Comment: $\sin 2\theta$ is not negative in $[0,\pi]$, $[2\pi,3\pi]$,$\ldots$ therefore for $\theta\in[0,\pi/2],[\pi,3\pi/2],\ldots$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\theta$ must lie in the 1st quadrant in order to make both $\sqrt{\cos \theta} $and $\sqrt{\sin \theta}$ real, therefore the general solution of the equation should be $\theta= 2 n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4} \text {, where } n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 2):

By squaring, you have established that any solution of the equation must be of the form $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}+k \pi$. However, not all numbers  with this form need to be solutions of the equation. Imagine a simpler situation, where you are solving $x = -\sqrt{x}$, and thus assuming that $x\ge 0$. When you square both sides of the equality, you obtain $x^2=x \Leftrightarrow x = 0 \vee x = 1$, but $x=1$ is clearly not a solution to the initial equation. This boils down to realising that $ a = b \Rightarrow a^2=b^2$ but $a^2=b^2 \not \Rightarrow a = b$.