# Was it right for my book to assume that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ is positive in finding $\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x\cos x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

**Question:**

Determine: $$\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x\cos x}dx$$

**My book's attempt:**

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x\cos x}dx$$

$$=\int\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}}{\sin x\cos x}dx$$

$$=\int\frac{\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}}}{\sin x\cos x}dx\tag{1}$$

$$...$$

My book assumed in $(1)$ that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are both positive. However, the question didn't mention that we are in the first quadrant. From the question, we can only understand that $\tan x$ is positive (because of $\sqrt{\tan x}$): $x$ could be in the 1st **or the third quadrant**. So, isn't my book making an invalid move in $(1)$?

Comment: I guess, they compute the integral for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$...

Comment: They have certainly reduced the domain of validity. Wether they are correct in the end or not, depends on the $\cdots$, because they may have reached an expression that, regardless of how it was obtained, turns out to be an antiderivative defined in the entire initial domain.

Comment: @PierreCarre ok sir, I understand. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: You have posted around 10 questions on the validity of substitutions in integrals. Almost all of them say the same thing @PierreCarre did. Maybe a bit of revisiting would help

Comment: 1. This was answered to you [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261791/21813). 2. I prefer Quanto's procedure, but if you'd like to take cases, in the third quadrant, the given integrand equals $\left(-\sin x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\cos x\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}.$

Comment: For concerned future users visiting, my question was answered satisfactorily by surb and pierrecarre's comments (ryang's comment is helpful too). Quanto's answer is very helpful too.

Answer (score 6):

You may avoid worrying about the domains of validity by integrating as follows

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x\cos x}dx
= \int\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\tan x}\sec^2 x \>dx
= \int \frac1{\sqrt{\tan x} }d({\tan x})=2 \sqrt{\tan x}
$$
which is valid for either domains.