# Equations and truth tables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Let's say I work on the inequality $|x-1|>x-2$ in the following way:

$$
|x-1|>x-2 ⇔ x-1≥0 \quad ∧ \quad |x-1|>x-2 \quad ∨ \quad x-1<0 \quad ∧ \quad |x-1|>x-2 \\
⇔  x-1≥0 \quad ∧ \quad x-1>x-2 \quad ∨ \quad x-1<0 \quad ∧ \quad -(x-1)>x-2 \\
⇔ x-1≥0 \quad ∧ \quad -1>-2 \quad ∨ \quad x-1<0 \quad ∧ \quad -(x-1)>x-2
$$

In $x-1≥0 ∧ -1>-2$ there is the true statement $-1>-2$ . So the truth value of the whole statment
$$
x-1≥0 ∧ -1>-2 
$$
only depends on $x-1≥0$ . If $x-1≥0$ is true, then the whole statment is true, if $x-1≥0$ is false then whole statment is false. So I should be able to write the following
$$
x-1≥0 ∧ -1>-2 ⇔ x-1≥0 
$$
I think that I can prove that I am allowed to write
$$
x-1≥0 ∧ -1>-2 ⇔ x-1≥0 
$$
with the help of a truth table in the following way:
We know that the statement $B$ is true. With this knowledge we analyse the statement
$$
A∧B⇔A 
$$
with the help of a truth table:

| $A$ | $B$ |  | $A$ | $∧$ | $B$ | $⇔$ | $A$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

1 for "true", 0 for "false". The first two columns show all the possible truth values the statements A and B can have.

As you can see in the truth table, the equivalence ⇔ has always the truth value of 1. This proves that if you have a statement B that is true, you can write
$$
A∧B⇔A .
$$
So coming back to the equations: this proves that I am allowed to write
$$
x-1≥0 ∧ -1>-2 ⇔ x-1≥0 .
$$

I also analysed this
$$
A∨B⇔A 
$$
statement in a similar way: We know that the statement B is false. With this knowledge we analyse the statement
$$
A∨B⇔A 
$$
with the help of a truth table:

| $A$ | $B$ |  | $A$ | $∨$ | $B$ | $⇔$ | $A$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |  | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

As you can see in the truth table, the equivalence ⇔ has always the truth value of 1.

So first I want to know, up to this point, is everything correct?

I have another question which is similar. Let's say I work on a set of equations and get to the following point:
$$
\frac{20}{x} = \sqrt{(41-x^2 )}  ∧  y=\frac{20}{x}
$$
Now, in a side-calculation, I work on the left equation by squaring it
$$
\frac{20}{x} = \sqrt{(41-x^2 )} ⟹ \frac{400}{x^2} =41-x^2
$$
Now I use this Information in my set of equations, like this:
$$
\frac{20}{x} = \sqrt{(41-x^2 )}  ∧  y=\frac{20}{x} ⟹ \frac{400}{x^2} =41-x^2  ∧  y=\frac{20}{x}
$$

I want to  check if I actually can write the Implication-Arrow "⟹" there. I do this by using a truth table again, in the following way:
We know that
$$
A⇒C
$$
is true (thats the squaring in the side-calculation). With this knowledge we analyse the statement
$$
A ∧ B ⇒ C ∧ B
$$
with the help of a truth table:

| $A$ | $B$ |  | $A$ | $∧$ | $B$ | $⟹$ | $C$ | $∧$ | $B$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ? | ? | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ? | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I put the question marks there because if $A$ is false, we don't know what truth value $C$ has, even if $A⇒C$ is a tautology. All we know from the tautology $A⇒C$ is, that if $A$ is true, then $C$ is also true.
The truth table proves that the statement
$$
A ∧ B ⇒ C ∧ B 
$$
with: $A⇒C$ is true

is always true. That means it's correct to write an implication arrow here:
$$
\frac{20}{x} = \sqrt{(41-x^2 )}  ∧  y=\frac{20}{x} ⟹ \frac{400}{x^2} =41-x^2  ∧  y=\frac{20}{x}
$$

Again I have analysed the same stuff with the logical OR $∨$ :
We know that
$$
A⇒C
$$
is true. With this knowledge we analyse the statement
$$
A ∨ B ⇒ C ∨ B
$$
with the help of a truth table:

| $A$ | $B$ |  | $A$ | $∨$ | $B$ | $⟹$ | $C$ | $∨$ | $B$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ? | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ? | ? | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |  | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

The truth table proves that the statement
$$
A ∨ B ⇒ C ∨ B 
$$
with: $A⇒C$ is true

is always true.

Are all these thoughts correct ?

---

**EDIT**

@ryang thank you for your answer.
Yes I do know about the quantifier ∀x. Maybe I'll write the following to lay some groundwork, so that you also know where I stand with my knowledge:
We can think of two predicates
$$
A(x):(x=2 \Rightarrow  x^2=4) \ \ \ \  \mathrm{and} \ \ \ \ B(x):(x^2=4 \Rightarrow x=2 )
$$
There are real numbers that turn the predicate $A(x)$ into a true statement for eg. $A(3)$ is true, $A(2)$ is true, $A(-2)$ is true. There are real numbers that turn the predicate $B(x)$ into a true statement for eg. $B(3)$ is true, $B(2)$ is true. We can easily see that $B(-2)$ is false.
Now it turns out that the statement
$$
\forall x\in \mathbb R: A(x)
$$
is a true statement and that the statement
$$
\forall x\in \mathbb R: B(x)
$$
is a false statement (just by looking at the truth value of $B(-2)$ ).
The reason that we definitely know that
$$
\forall x\in \mathbb R: A(x)
$$
is a true statement is because we know that
$$
t_1=t_2 \Rightarrow f(t_1)=f(t_2)
$$
(with a function $f$)
is a tautology, because that's just what functions do (input→output). So when we do our usual rearrangings of equations, we actually use functions on both sides of the equation. If the function $f$ is injective we can actually put the equivalence arrow $⇔$ there. The function used in the predicate $A(x)$ looks like this
$$
f:t\mapsto t^2
$$
First I wanted to know, what do you think about the first two truth tables? Are they and the thoughts behind them  (how I set them up and how I used them to prove my point) correct?

Regarding your first point, I meant it this way:
We know that
$$
A⇒C
$$
is true/a tautology. With this knowledge we analyse the statement
$$
A ∧ B ⇒ C ∧ B
$$
with the help of a truth table.

So I don't think that the truth table you posted is actually correct or maybe I should say, it doesn't represent what I am trying to do. Because the statement
$$
A⇒C
$$
should always have a truth value of 1 since it is a tautology. This should represent the step in the side-calculation where I squared the equation

$$
\frac{20}{x} = \sqrt{(41-x^2 )}  ⟹ \frac{400}{x^2} =41-x^2.
$$

I was trying to prove with a truth table that I can actually write the Implication-Arrow $⟹$ here
$$
\frac{20}{x} = \sqrt{(41-x^2 )}  ∧  y=\frac{20}{x} ⟹ \frac{400}{x^2} =41-x^2  ∧  y=\frac{20}{x}.
$$

That's why the third and fourth truth table look the way they do. Is it possible to set the truth tables up the way that I did to prove my point?

Regarding your point:
"Furthermore, it is not generally valid to determine the truth of a predicate-logic formula by simply dropping its quantifiers and ignoring the internal structure of $Q(x)$ by pretending that it is just $Q$."

But are we not doing this actually pretty often? For example, let's say I work on the following set of equations

$$
y=\frac{1}{6}x^2 \ \  \land \ \  x^2+y^2=16
$$
like this
$$
y=\frac{1}{6}x^2 \ \  \land \ \  x^2+y^2=16 \iff 6y=x^2 \ \  \land \ \ x^2+y^2=16 \iff 6y=x^2 \ \  \land 6y+y^2=16 \\ 
\iff 6y=x^2 \ \  \land \ \ (y=2 \lor y=-8) \iff 6y=x^2 \ \land \ y=2 \ \ \lor \ \ 6y=x^2 \ \land \ y=-8   
$$
The reason I knew that this step
$$
6y=x^2 \ \  \land \ \ (y=2 \lor y=-8) \iff 6y=x^2 \ \land \ y=2 \ \ \lor \ \ 6y=x^2 \ \land \ y=-8   
$$
is valid, is because earlier I looked at the truth table of
$$
A \ \land \ (B \lor C) \iff A \ \land \ B \ \ \lor \ \ A \ \land \ C.  
$$
The truth table shows me that
$$
A \ \land \ (B \lor C) \iff A \ \land \ B \ \ \lor \ \ A \ \land \ C.  
$$
is a tautology, so that's why I used this when I worked on my sets of equations.

I hope you see my point.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes, these implications are all correct, and truth tables are a sensible way of demonstrating them. With your third and fourth tables, given you have $3$ variables, usually a truth table with $2^3 = 8$ rows is used, instead of employing question marks. But, I do follow what you were going for.

Comment: @TheoBendit yeah I am aware that there should be 2^3=8  rows when having 3 variables in a "standard" truth table. But (and I think you noticed that) in my question the truth tables are not the standard ones where all statements can have a 0 or a 1 as a truth value. For example looking at my first truth table where B did only have the truth value of 1. Or looking at the third truth table where the truth value of C did directly depend on the truth value of A. Do you know what I mean? But all in all you are saying that all my thoughts here are correct, did I understand that right?

Comment: The second half of [Using logical implication to analyse mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4503325/21813) and Addendum 2 of [What is a valid step in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261791/21813) might be of interest.

Comment: @ryang thank you but I don't think that the stuff you linked answers my question 

Comment: @Florian Yes, your thoughts are correct, and yes, I knew what you meant with all of your non-standard truth tables. I wouldn't worry too much about them anyway. Truth tables are primarily a pedagogical tool, designed to anchor abstract concerns about logical arguments in terms of something you can compute. They're bad if you have $4$ or more variables, and basically useless once you introduce quantifiers. You should eventually make more intuitive arguments, and/or use established implications (as theorems). Just use tables to the point where you are convinced by your logical steps.

Comment: For the second table, where you said "I also analysed this with the logical OR: We know that the statement B is false": If *the* logical OR refers to the only logical OR mentioned before: $\ldots\vee (x-1<0 \wedge -(x-1)>x-2)$, and *the* statement B refers to its second operand, then this statement B is not always false.

Comment: Are you acquainted with the quantifier `∀x` ?

Comment: @peterwhy when I said "I also analysed this with the logical OR: We know that the statement B is false" I was not referring to the inequality at the beginnig. I used the inequality only as an introduction so that everyone knew where I was coming from

Comment: @ryang [updated comment] I am very thankful for your answer. I have two small questions left. I don't think that they are worth starting a whole new question post. 1. Did you also check my first two truth tables in my original question? Are they correct the way I set them up? 2. Regarding the start of your addendum  “No, the latter is not a tautology, merely universally true for each $(t1,t2)$.” Could you tell me if the following is correct:
We know that $\forall x\in \mathbb R: (x=2\Rightarrow x^2=4)$ is true because ..

Comment: …we know that $\forall t_1,t_2 \in S: (t_1=t_2\Rightarrow f(t_1)=f(t_2)) $ is true. $S$ is "the set of all terms". So $S$ contains for example terms like: $2x + 7$ , $\frac{3x+7}{2}$ , $x$ or $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your clarification **EDIT**, I have revised my Answer correspondingly, and addressed your new questions as an Addendum below.

1. > The truth table proves that the statement "$A ∧ B ⇒ C ∧ B$ with: $A⇒C$ is true" is always true.

   Does [“with”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4266064/21813) mean
   ‘if’ or ‘and’? If the former, then you mean $$(A \to C)\to(A ∧ B  \to  C ∧ B),\tag{*}$$ so why not simply construct *this* truth
   table instead? It immediately confirms that $(*)$ is a tautology, as required.
   \begin{array}{ccc|c@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}c@{}c}
   A&B&C&(&(&A&\rightarrow&C&)&\rightarrow&(&(&A&\land&B&)&\rightarrow&(&C&\land&B&)&)&)\\\hline
   1&1&1&&&1&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&&\\
   1&1&0&&&1&0&0&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&1&1&&0&&0&0&1&&&\\
   1&0&1&&&1&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&0&0&&1&&1&0&0&&&\\
   1&0&0&&&1&0&0&&\mathbf{1}&&&1&0&0&&1&&0&0&0&&&\\
   0&1&1&&&0&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&0&1&&1&&1&1&1&&&\\
   0&1&0&&&0&1&0&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&0&1&&1&&0&0&1&&&\\
   0&0&1&&&0&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&0&0&&1&&1&0&0&&&\\
   0&0&0&&&0&1&0&&\mathbf{1}&&&0&0&0&&1&&0&0&0&&& \end{array}

   Side note: $(*)$ is logically equivalent to $$ (A \to C)∧(A ∧ B)   \to  C ∧ B$$ (because $P\to(Q\to R)\equiv P\land Q\to R$); perhaps this is more obviously tautological?
2. > That means that $$20/x=\sqrt{41-x^2}  ⟹ 400/x^2 =41-x^2$$ implies that $$20/x=\sqrt{41-x^2}  ∧  y=20/x ⟹ 400/x^2 =41-x^2  ∧  y=20/x.$$

   Let's symbolise this as $$(Ax  \to Cx)\to (Ax  ∧  Bx\to Cx 
   ∧  Bx).\tag#$$

   Here's your argument, made explicit. Yes, it is sound!

   1. $(Ax →Cx)$ is true and $(*)$ is a tautology;
   2. thus, $(Ax →Cx)$ is true and $(\#)$ a tautology;
   3. thus, $(Ax  ∧  Bx\to Cx     ∧  Bx)$ is true, as required.

---

**ADDENDUM**

> we definitely know that [image]
> is true because we know that [image]
> is a tautology.

No, the latter is **not a tautology**, merely **universally true** for each $(t_1,t_2).$

What you mean to say is that the former is true assuming mathematical axioms and the given context, that is, *mathematically* true.

> We know that $A⇒C$ is true/a tautology.

$(A⇒C)$ is certainly true *in your particular context*.

But $(A⇒C)$ is [**not** a tautology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4507714/21813): its truth table has $4$ rows, with one $\text‘0\text’$ below $\text‘⇒\text’.$

> With this knowledge, we analyse the statement $A ∧ B ⇒ C ∧ B$ with the help of a truth table.

So, you are using $(A⇒C)$ as a **premise** to check whether it is valid to **conclude** that $(A∧B⇒C∧B)$ is true.

In other words, you are checking whether the inference $$(A \to C)\to(A ∧ B  \to  C ∧ B),\tag{*}$$ is valid (i.e., *logically* true); in yet other words, you are checking whether $(*)$ is a tautology.

> So I don't think that the truth table you posted represents what I am trying to do.

My truth table for $(*)$ *directly* demonstrates exactly that $(A⇒C)$ **tautologically implies** $(A∧B⇒C∧B),$ as required.

(Observe that it contains $3$ variables has $2^3=8$ rows, so is a *full* truth table.)

To wit: let's hunt for any row in which $(A⇒C)$ is true and $(A∧B⇒C∧B)$ false. (Notice that in this search, we can *ignore* all rows in which $(A⇒C)$ is false, since they won't contain what we're after.) The fact that no such row exists corresponds to the fact that $(*)$'s main connective has no $\text‘0\text’$ below it.

In a truth table, each row corresponds to each truth assignment (case) of $(A,B,C).$ Think of each row as a particular context (‘[interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic))’).

In *your* particular context, $(A⇒C)$ is true; however, this is irrelevant: investigating *tautological/logical* truth means to investigate the truth *regardless* of context.

> Because the statement A⇒C should always have a truth value of 1 since it is a tautology.

Because $(A⇒C)$ is *not* a tautology, a full truth table *will* contain rows in which $(A⇒C)$ has truth value $0.$

> what do you think about how I set up my truth tables?

Your reasoning process for all those truth tables is *valid*.

And, using an indirect process and its partial truth table, you have *correctly* proven that $(*)$ is a tautology.

The alternative procedure that I showed is straightforward and mostly mechanical: formalise the given statement, [obtain](https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html) its truth table, then conclude, from the all $\text‘1\text’$'s, that it is a tautology.

To be clear: your partial truth table is an excerpt of the truth table that I gave.

Comment: I think that I understood your answer but maybe let me try to say it in my own words: Your truth table shows that each and every time that the sentence $(A⟹C)$ is true, the sentence $(A∧B⟹C∧B)$ is also true. That means, because 
$$20/x=\sqrt{41-x^2}  ⟹ 400/x^2 =41-x^2$$
is true (for all  $x∈ \mathbb R$ ), this 
$$20/x=\sqrt{41-x^2}  ∧  y=20/x ⟹ 400/x^2 =41-x^2  ∧  y=20/x$$ 
is also true (for all $x∈ \mathbb R$).

Comment: No, _not_ with the implicit universal quantification. Invoking [universal generalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) at this stage will complexify things (my initial answer had addressed this, it got significantly beyond the level of the OP Question, so I deleted it before posting; I now regret not having just submitted then editing it away, which would've saved a copy for reference).  At this point of your analysis, we're merely dealing with an arbitrary $x,$ which is why you can consider just the formulae's truth-functional form and use propositional logic.

Comment: Oh so then I should have written: ... That means, because $$ 20/x=\sqrt{41-x^2}  ⟹ 400/x^2 =41-x^2 $$ is true (for an arbitrary $x∈ \mathbb R$), this $$20/x=\sqrt{41-x^2}  ∧  y=20/x ⟹ 400/x^2 =41-x^2  ∧  y=20/x$$ is also true (for an arbitrary $x∈ \mathbb R$).

Comment: 1. I guess, but remember, letting $x$ be arbitrary was already declared prior to the current excerpt (that is, it is unseen by us), and there's no need to keep repeating the fact. $\quad$ 2. Instead of belabouring my point from our deleted conversation, Imma just cite [Theo's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511512/equations-and-truth-tables/4511586?noredirect=1#comment9472837_4511512).