# Propositional logic, predicate logic and equations

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I have $$ 6y=x^2  \quad ∧\quad   (y=2   \quad ∨\quad  y=-8)$$$$
\iff (6y=x^2 \quad ∧ \quad y=2 ) \quad ∨\quad  (6y=x^2 \quad ∧\quad y=-8). \tag1$$
Is it correct to say that step (1) is valid because $$
A ∧(B ∨ C)  ⇔ (A∧B)∨   (A∧C)\tag2$$ is a tautology?

But does (2) being a tautology really legitimize what I did in (1)? After all (2) belongs to propositional logic while (1) belongs to predicate logic.

Here is my attempt to answer my question:

Yes, I would think that it is enough to show that (2) is a tautology to legitimize what I did in (1). The reason is that the truth table of (2) contains ALL the possible combinations of logical values (“true” or ” false”) of $A$, $B$ and $C$.  Even though $6y=x^2$ , $y=2$ and $y=-8$ are predicates, they turn into a true or false sentence after I plugged in certain numbers. For example, when I plug in $y=2$ ,$x=\sqrt{12}$ into (1): this $6y=x^2$ and this $y=2$ becomes true, while this $y=-8$ becomes false. But that’s a situation I can find in the truth table of (2) as the row where
$$
A=1 \ \ \ \ B=1 \ \ \ \ C=0 \ \  .
$$
For everything that can happen in (1) I can find a corresponding row from the truth table of (2). That’s why the truth table of (2) “covers” everything that can happen in (1). And that’s why the tautology in (2) legitimizes the step in (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$ 6y=x^2  \quad ∧\quad   (y=2   \quad ∨\quad  y=-8)$$$$
> \iff (6y=x^2 \quad ∧ \quad y=2 ) \quad ∨\quad  (6y=x^2 \quad ∧\quad y=-8). \tag1$$ does $$A ∧(B ∨ C)  ⇔ (A∧B)∨   (A∧C)\tag2$$  being a tautology really legitimize what I did in (1)? After all (2) belongs to propositional logic while (1) belongs to predicate logic.

The proposition $Q$ is the truth-functional form of the proposition $\big(\exists x\;(x>0 \land x<10)\big).$

The proposition $A$ is the truth-functional form of the predicate $Axy.$

By the substitutions \begin{align}A&:=(Axy:=)&&6y=x^2,\\B&:=(By:=)&&y=2,\\C&:=(Cy:=)&&y=-8,\end{align} the proposition $(2)$ is the truth-functional form of the predicate $(1).$

Thus, since $(2)$ is a tautology, $(1)$ is also a tautology. Notice that this argument was made in point #2 of [our previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4511586/21813). We say that the two sides of $(1)$ are tautologically equivalent to each other.

Naturally, $(1)$'s formalisation $$Axy ∧(By ∨ Cy)  ⇔ (Axy∧By)∨   (Axy∧Cy)\tag3$$ is also a tautology.

Predicate logic is an extension of, not complementary to, propositional logic.

Pertinently, your above analysis is applicable only because $(1)$ involves *no* quantification, because it is in the midst of dealing with *arbitrary* $x$ and $y.$

**Addendum**

> Could you pls explain to me what you mean exactly by "truth-functional form"?

Sure; let me know if this algorithm is unclear. To determine the truth-functional form of a predicate-logic formula:

1. working from left-to-right, underline the entire scope of each quantifier, including the quantifier itself;
2. underline each remaining atomic formula;
3. assign a symbol—usually a capital letter, representing an atomic propositional-logic proposition—to every underlined formula, assigning the same symbol to two formulae if and only if they are identical.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 1.: Could you pls explain to me what you mean exactly by "truth-functional form" (or link me a site where I can read about it)? I know about truth functions, for example the logical connective $\land$ can be thought of as a function who takes in a couple of truth values, like $(1,1)$, and maps this couple to a truth value, in this case $1$. 2.: You denote predicates like this $Ax$. Until now I have only seen something like this $A(x)$ used for denoting predicates. Is your notation...

Comment: ...just a style you like more or is there a difference between $Ax$ and $A(x)$?

Comment: Axyz:=A(x,y,z). Too many parentheses very quickly make formal logic formulae harder to human-parse (and type), and I'm lazy.

Comment: Regarding your Addendum: So I would underline the atomic formula/predicate $6y=x^2$ and assign to it the letter $A$ which should represent an atomic proposition. As I am doing this, is it correct to say that I am treating/looking at the predicate $6y=x^2$ like it would be just an atomic proposition?

Comment: Thanks for asking: in first-order logic, the atomic formula $6y=x^2$ is not a sentence (it is a [predicate or open formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231999/21813)), whereas in propositional logic it becomes a(n atomic) sentence. The truth-functional form of a FOL formula just means its PL form, i.e., what it becomes in the context of PL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!